# "Cannot find function getFiles in object test" error when trying to list pdf file in a drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to run this (very) simple script :

```
function listFilesInFolder() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

};
```

but I have the following error

`TypeError: Cannot find function getFiles in object testupwork. (line 4, file "Code")`

Log is working properly

Comment: Why do you think a `File` object has the method `getFiles`? Sounds like you used the wrong `DriveApp` method...

Comment: thanks for your comment but I don't know what to answer you. If it is not the `getFiles` method how can I read the list of pdf file I have in my folder... ?

Comment: `getFiles()` is absolutely the method you should call from a `Folder` object to access the `Files` in that `Folder`. As the script error states, `getFiles()` is not a method of a `File` object, even if you name its variable "`folder`". Review documentation of the `DriveApp` class and methods.

Answer (score 0):

While on Google Drive REST API file is used both for handling files and folders on the Apps Script Drive Service there are a specific class for files and another for folders.

Change

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

to

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid